# Avoiding viruses 101

Tags: anti-virus, malware, phishing

I'm looking to send out an email to my users to give them advice on avoiding getting viruses and phishing emails.

I've found http://www.sonicwall.com/furl/phishing/ which is a bit dated and is primarily for phishing but still applies a bit for viruses.

Does anyone have a newer guide to educate the users on both viruses and phishing emails?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the .edu site as they are generally targeted to people who are not admins and are great resources when trying to teach people about safe computing.  An example is http://buckeyesecure.osu.edu/SafeComputing/Index The information is organized very well and is a bit more flashy then http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_virus .  Normal users may pay more attention to the .edu then a dry wiki.

Answer (score 1):

Greetings, everyone.

While we here at $COMPANY strive to skillfully administer world-class security technologies to ensure our IT infrastructure and software best serves your needs with the utmost in safety and reliability, we can't do it without you!  We invite you to watch the following video for some tips on safe Internet usage, both at home and in the workplace.  You can view the video by clicking on this link:

http://www.microsoft.com/showcase/en/us/details/b11071c9-71f6-4220-a513-0eebc64a8479

If you have any questions, feel free to contact us at any time.  Thanks and have a great day!

Comment: +1 if the video link is malicious. +2 if you also go for "please find attached a .exe file which contains a demo of how to avoid viruses"

Answer (score 1):

The email that I send out every now and then mentions the following points:

- If in doubt, ask the support group for help.
- "From:" addresses on emails can be easily faked, if there's anything odd about a message, don't trust where it says it's from.  Learn how to see the real from address.
- Never do something that an email tells you to do.  If a message says "forward this to everyone you know," don't do it.  If a message says "click on the link immediately," stop and think about it.
- Think about whether the message makes sense.  Is it strange to get a message from that person right now?  Is it strange for them to send you that file?
- We strongly recommend that you access your mail in "plain text mode."  This removes most of the formatting from the message and makes it harder for a "bad" message to disguise itself.  Contact the support group for more information.

I have about half the company convinced to use plain text, and about a third of the people can check the headers in Outlook w/out calling for help, but we still get a few calls a week (about 150 people).